# Google apps script : calling jdbc required permissions?

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script

i've gscript inside a spreadsheet, if i add and run a function calling this code :

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://sql4.freesqldatabase.com:3306/sql427377', 'sql427377', 'my_pass');
```

it works !

But if i copy/paste the same code in a google app script :

```
function doGet() { 
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate(); 
} 
function getSql(){ 
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://sql4.freesqldatabase.com:3306/sql427377', 'sql427377', 'my_pass'); 
}
```

even if i don't call the function, i've just paste the code, i ve got this message on execution of my script : 
"Vous devez disposer des autorisations requises pour pouvoir effectuer cette action."
"You must have the required permissions to perform this action."

I don't understand why... need help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions in a script project are asked **for every service present in this project**. Wether you actually call a function using this service or not is not important.

For example, if I have an `onOpen()` function in a script and another function that sends emails, I will be asked permission for `mailApp service` even if I simply try to run `onOpen()`.

If your spreadsheet does not ask anything about Jdbc, it means that the project was already authorized for this service (and you probably forgot it) and the behavior you describe in your other project (the doGet one , but it would be the same in any other project) is normal.

If you want to check this, simply add a call to another Google service in a dummy function and try to execute another function that used to work without warning... You'll get the authorization request as expected.

Comment: ok thank you for your help. 
I remove my call to jdbc.
i try to add a call to another Google service : CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar(); in my script (doGet one)
But i don't manage to get the authorization request.
Is there a solution to get the authorization list for my script ?
Thank you again...

Comment: ok it works ! it seems i va to redeploy and use the /exec url and not the /dev url to to the authorization request.
Maybe ... :)

Comment: You should get the authorization request from the script editor too. Please consider accepting the answer. Thx