# Random Error - permissions needed to call getConnection()

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script with a onEdit() function defined to update some data in a MYSQL database using jdbc. 
I have set this function "onEdit" using the triggers UI to run "From spreadsheet" > "on edit".

It works most of the time then randomly fails with the following error in logs:

```
You do not have permission to call getConnection at [unknown function](Code:7)
```

Line 7 is:

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xxxx", "xxx", "xx");
```

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46548237/script-stopping-may-be-due-to-onedit-spreadsheetapp-call-and-then-documentapp/46548619#46548619) will help you. In short you might be having a simple Trigger for `onEdit`, what you need is an installable Trigger.

Comment: I do believe I have a installable trigger setup. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908498/google-apps-script-calling-jdbc-required-permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this weird behavior by rather creating the Installable trigger programmatically than via the UI.

1. I renamed the "onEdit" function to "onEditStatus".
2. Created a Initialize function to create the trigger (before creating it also deletes prev triggers) See below:

function Initialize() {

```
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for(var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var builder = ScriptApp.newTrigger("onEditStatus")
  .forSpreadsheet(ss)
  .onEdit()
  .create();

};
```

This fixed my "You do not have permission to call getConnection at" issue.

Comment: Thanks , its has really save my time !

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation might help to understand the issue. onEdit event in Apps Script is a restricted event that does not trigger the OAuth flow. Probably due to performance reasons or some other technical difficulties linked to how Google Apps work.

It's not a weird behaviour. In documentation (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), in section about simple triggers they say this:

> They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a
> simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires
> authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the
> Language service, which is anonymous.

The best solution, to my best understanding, is described above - install-able triggers.